# What version of BlackBerry OS can I target with WebWorks SDK 2.0

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-webworks

It looks like I can't install WebWorks SDK 2.1 in Eclipse without having to build everything manually...screw that. I need to build my app for BB SDK 6, but I keep getting build errors on 6.0 API calls. I've set my default JRE to BB 6, but I seem to be getting facet errors.

The WebWorks Static Web Module doesn't want to play nice with everything else.

I'm I hosed on developing for BB6 or am I doing something wrong?!

---

Someone on the BB Dev forums mentioned the bbwp.properties file...apparently it has a  property where you would specify the BB runtime or BB component pack. If this is the correct approach could someone provide an example of the  setting?

Comment: Ok, so I found out that it is indeed possible to target BB OS6, but we had to use the WebWorks packager (bbwp.exe) to package the project instead of Eclipse

Comment: will you plz share any detail of this process as i am also trying something similar?